# Can I change Type of Default SharePoint Columns?

Tags: 2010, site-column

My question is Simple. I want to Change Type of SharePoint Default Column (Site Column) like **Title**. I want to Change its type from **Singe Line of Text** to **Look Up**. Is it Possible ?

Comment: This is Exact Duplicate Question :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/0074772c-9b8a-4bd6-8048-81cda3c0c78f

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  You can set the Title field to hidden in the content type and create a new field to replace it if you wish.

Comment: You are right Russell.I just wants to know that is it possible or not and I also know that it is not recommended to change the type of SharePoint Default Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched through Internet and i found this Solution. I write this code in Feature Receiver and It Worked for me.

First I found solution using PowerShell from [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/add-and-modify-the-existing-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/) site and I tried using Code and got the solution.

```
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            SPField field = web.Fields["Title"];
            field.Type = SPFieldType.DateTime;
            field.Update();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will be causing yourself a world of hurt if you do this, even though it is technically possible. Please don't.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your suggestion. I know that it is not good to mess with SharePoint default columns. I just wants to know that is it possible or not and I was just learning that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend messing with the title column. It's a system column and 
it's better to be left alone.